# R Sort/order specific named columns containing numbers and letters (data.frame)

Tags: r

I would like to know how can I order or sort named columns in R containing letters and numbers using base R

This is my sample data:

```
Names <- c("Name1","Name2")
X2 <- c("10","1")
X1 <- c("7","5")
X10 <- c("8","3")
db <- data.frame(Names, X2, X1, X10)
```

Output/view(data.frame):

```
Names X2 X1 X10
Name1 10  7  5
Name2  1  5  7
```

Let's say I want to sort or order the columns containing the "X" character at the beginning but using its numeric "value"? expecting this output:

```
Names X1 X2 X10
Name1  7 10  5
Name2  5  1  7
```

This is my current solution, I hope this helps anyone :)

```
db_names <- colnames(db[,2:ncol(db)])
db_names <- db_names[order(nchar(db_names), db_names)]
cbind(Names = db[,1],db[,db_names])
```

Output:

```
Names X1 X2 X10
Name1  7 10  5
Name2  5  1  7
```

The number of columns in my real data frame is greater, a dynamic solution will be appreciated.

Thank you for your attention and sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# With the pipe
db %>% 
  select(Names, num_range("X", range = 1:10))

# Without the pipe
select(db, Names, num_range("X", range = 1:10))
```

Both return:

```
  Names X1 X2 X10
1 Name1  7 10   8
2 Name2  5  1   3
```

This assumes that all columns have the prefix "X". Adjust the range accordingly.

---

One base R solution might be:

```
db[order(as.numeric(substring(colnames(db), 2)), na.last = FALSE)]
```

This returns:

```
  Names X1 X2 X10
1 Name1  7 10   8
2 Name2  5  1   3
```

Which is similar to the other answer but uses `substring` instead of `gsub`. This also produces the following warning message:

> ```
> Warning message:
> In order(as.numeric(substring(colnames(db), 2)), na.last = FALSE) :
>   NAs introduced by coercion
> ```

This is because we can't turn `Names` into a numeric value:

```
as.numeric(substring(colnames(db), 2))
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> NAs introduced by coercion
> ```

```
[1] NA  2  1 10
```

Comment: Thank you @tyluRp work's perfectly, do you know a base R solution?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It gives a warning message but is still ordering the columns correctly.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much pal! @tyluRp

Answer (score 1):

```
db[,order(as.numeric(gsub("X","",names(db))),na.last=F)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
I have extended the sample data to make sure the alpha numeric sort works

```
Names <- c("Name1","Name2")
X2 <- c("10","1")
X1 <- c("7","5")
X10 <- c("8","5")
X11 <- c("6","5")
```

using `mixedorder` from the package `gtools`

```
db <- db[mixedorder(colnames(db))]
```

**Output:**

```
Names X1 X2 X10 X11
Name1  7 10   8   6
Name2  5  1   5   5
```

Comment: This won't work if there is a column named `X10` though. For example, `db[sort(colnames(db))]` with colnames `X2`, `X10` will return `X10`, `X2`.

Comment: thanks @tyluRp for pointing out the exception, I have updated the solution

Comment: Thank you @ImranAli!, i did not mention that i would prefer a base R solution but i will use the package for now, if you know a base R solution let me know! thanks